# Can't play movie on TV with DTS audio codec

Tags: audio, tv, codec

Most movies have DTS audio codec but my TV can't play it. Is there anything can be done about it? Maybe somehow change codec? Or maybe you can download audio in separate file?

If it matters I play it from hard drive connected with USB.

Comment: You can re-encode the audio stream with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), [virtualdub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) or [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: @Banthar re-encoding won't affect video quality?

Comment: If the video works fine, you can re-encode just the audio. There should be an option to copy the video stream.

Comment: @Banthar I tried to convert with VLC and when it was converted there was only sound and it was silent